# React Native - FlatList with 2 columns are not acting as expected

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm using a FlatList with 2 columns, it works fine except in few rows, it takes the complete row, instead of half of it. I have this issue both in Android and iOS. I tried raising an issue in Flatlist Github but was of no use - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19156#issuecomment-387200626

```
<FlatList 
    vertical 
    numColumns={2} 
    extraData={this.state} 
    data={this.state.bikeCities} 
    style={styles.CityListView} 
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} 
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()} 
    renderItem={({item:rowData, index}) => { 
    if(rowData.country_id == this.state.selectedCountryId) 
    { 
    return( 
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.FlatListStyle} 
            onPress={() => this.props.citySelection(rowData, 
            this.state.selectedView)}> 
              <Text style={styles.cityText}> . {rowData.name}</Text> 
          </TouchableOpacity> 
         ); 
    } 
}}/>
```

Here is the screenshot of obtained result -

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TtPp.png)

Anybody can help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you are conditionally rendering the row item, I think the blank that you are seeing on the list is because the condition didn't meet for those items

`if (rowData.country_id == this.state.selectedCountryId)`

If you need to render item based on some selection, then preprocess / filter the data beforehand and then pass to FlatList.

Hope this will help!